# Function that reverses any array - C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I wrote a code that reverses any array, it's meaning from the end to the start, but it is not working with the type of char.
How would I wrote a code that reverts any array (int, float, char)?
for example the original array is: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
After the run, the array will be: 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

void reverseArr ( void *arr, unsigned size);

void main ()
{

    char a[SIZE] = {'a','b','c','d','e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'};

    reverseArr (a, SIZE);

}

void reverseArr ( void *arr, unsigned size)
{
    int *start, *end, temp;

    start=(int*)arr;
    end=(int*)arr+9;

    while (start<end)
    {
        temp=*start;
        *start=*end;
        *end=temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean by _any array (int, flaot, char)_ simple type or complex (struct, pointer ...) ?

Answer (score 5):

You cast the `void` pointer to an `int` pointer.

On your platform `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)` probably. So you don't traverse the array char by char.

You can't write a general function like that, without passing the size of the elements.

```
void reverseArr ( void *arr, unsigned len_array, unsigned size_element)
{
  char* start = (char*) arr;

  ....
  start += size_element;
  ....
}
```

since `sizeof(char) == 1` by design, you can traverse the buffer with pointers to `char`. Just move the right number of chars as dictated by `sizeof(type)`.

```
reverseArr (a, SIZE, sizeof(a[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you need to know what type of elements this array holds. Operator of advancing pointer makes certain assumption - the next element lies in memory `sizeof(type)` bytes further.

If you want to write generic version you should pass sizeof element along and do proper pointer arithmetics.

Comment: You can define a generic function which takes as argument a copy callback implemented by the user. Something like `void reserveArr(void *, unsigned int, void (*cpyfunc)(void *, void*))`